# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL

Tags: linux, ubuntu, c++, c, opengl

I'm on ubuntu 18.04 and when I run on the terminal:

> g ++ opengl_test.cpp -o firstOpenGlApp -lglut -lGLU -lGL

I have this error:

> /usr/bin/ld: can not find -lGL

if anyone could help me I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `libGL.so` library. Fix by installing the `libgl1` package:

`sudo apt-get install libgl1`

Notes:

- `libgl1` is a vendor neutral GL library. Alternatively, you could install `libgl1-mesa-dev`, which is an OpenGL implementation, and also provides `libGL.so`.
- When using the `-l` linker (`/usr/bin/ld`) option for specifying a library, the `lib`  file prefix and `.so` suffix are omitted. Therefore, with `-lGL` we tell the linker to link against the `libGL.so` shared object.
- If you're unsure as to which package provides the library you need, try to look it up in Ubuntu's package search: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libGL.so.1